# Hortonworks HDP ambari AWS EC2 heartbeat lost

Tags: hadoop, hortonworks-data-platform

HDP cluster deployed successfully on AWS EC2. After restart of the HDP cluster nodes, heartbeat lost from ambari server as all Public and Private IP’s and DNS are changed.

Where in ambari server we can configure new IP’s or DNS ??

Answer (score 1):

First, Ambari requires to have FQHN for all your nodes. It is best practice to assign proper hostnames on all your nodes.

A simple word-around for getting back the heartbeat on your Ambari server is to run the following on all your clients nodes:

```
sudo ambari-agent restart your_ambari.server.hostname.com
```

It worked for me on Ambari 2.0 and Ubuntu 12. Good luck!